# TryUpdateModel Asp.Net MVC is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to learn how to use TryUpdateModel but I cannot get it to work, you can find my code below:

> Controller Side

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace EFW6.Controllers
{

    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Home/
        private WorkFlowContext context = new WorkFlowContext();
        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            return View();
        }



        [HttpPost]
        public string UploadFile(FormCollection form)
        {
            Files file = new Files();

            if (TryUpdateModel(file, form.ToValueProvider()))
            {
                return "True " + file.filePath;
            }
            else 
            {
                return "False";
            }

        }


    }
}
```

> View Side

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "index";
}

<h2>@Model</h2>

<form method="post" action="Home/UploadFile">
    <input type="text" name="filePath">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

> Model Class

```
class Files
{
    public string filePath;
}
```

When I return the value of the file path it returns nothing while it returns the value True for as a result for the operation.

Comment: Why do not you use viewmodels?

Comment: for curiosity  I want to know how it works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that I am using field instead of property in the ***Files*** Class

I had to change it to be like this

```
class Files
{
    public string FilePath { get; set; }
}
```